# Building advice for "hunched" mech lower torso design?

Tags: building, ldd

Another mech based question, let me clean up as best I can...

So, in LDD, I'm working on an Evangelion Unit from the popular manga and anime, Neon Genesis Evangelion, and have decided to build EVA Unit 01 (Picture [here](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71LTvkvJg6L._SY879_.jpg)).

I've built the entire legs section ("lower" quarters) of the Unit, but am having difficulty capturing the "hunched" nature of the mech in Lego, let alone LDD. I don't even know where to start.

I did find this image online to try and assist me in replicating something similar, but it hasn't been of much use ([here](http://images.mocpages.com/user_images/43690/1433564952m_SPLASH.jpg)). But this image should give a general idea of what I am hoping to achieve in LDD.

Any advice would greatly be appreciated.

As always, thanks for viewing!

Comment: Hi GipsyD! I'm afraid I can't see any questions in the text, aside from the one in the title which is unfortunately too broad. Could you please edit the question to include one question whose answer can reasonably fit in this QA format?

Comment: @zovits, Unfortunately, I think this is as simple as I can get it without sounding completely obscure. But never fear, I have found a solution to this question, of which can be found below...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer is pretty long and complex, so bear with me.

After a couple hours of toying around with LDD, I have finally come up with a design that suits my needs fully within the realm of "traditional" Lego Building techniques.

After digging around in the sub-categories in LDD, I stumbled across this block ([here](https://img.brickowl.com/files/image_cache/large/lego-hinge-cylinder-1-x-3-locking-with-1-finger-and-2-stubs-on-ends-with-hole-30554-27.jpg)). This brick is essentially what made this entire build possible, as it allowed for the "hunching" for the lower abdomen to be captured.

To capture the hunching nature of this mech, I constructed 3 of these shapes to serve as the building blocks for the lower abdomen.

[image: Exhibit A]

In the middle of the piece referenced above, a short staff was passed through down the centre of the piece in the hole provided in the centre. This assembly is then connected to a 1x1 brick with studs on all faces except the base. The piece of the staff that is sticking out at the back is covered up with a 1x1 cylindrical piece, making room for the "spinal" assembly of the mech. The entire assembly is then covered up with decorative assemblies and facades, as seen in the picture above.

The result can be seen below --

[image: Exhibit B]

[image: Exhibit C]

[image: Exhibit D]

[image: Exhibit E]

[image: Exhibit F]

Unfortunately, no LDD file is provided, only images.

***UPDATE***

As requested by Aziraphale, here is a breakdown of one of the assemblies making up the hunched nature of the Evangelion Unit. Note the short staff going through the piece reference above, mounted to a 1x1 brick with studs on all faces, before being finished in a 1x1 cylindrical piece with a 1x2 detail plate.

[image: Exhibit G]

Comment: Hi GipsyD, can you please show how the "spinal" element is connected to the surrounding purple elements? This seems to be useful also for other cases with odd angles.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean the white piece at the back of each section?

Comment: The "spinal" element is the white piece at the back of each assembly, which is connected to the assembly via the 1x1 cylindrical piece, fitted with a 1x1 round piece with a hole in it.

Comment: No, I mean how the grey hinge piece is connected to the black and to the purple parts. An exploded view drawing would be very helpful.

Comment: @Aziraphale, of course, will update the answer ASAP

Comment: Wonderful! The staff is a "bar, 3L", right?  Does it sit tightly in the hinge piece, or does it move?

Comment: You would be correct. The bar that connects the hinge to the assembly is a 3L Bar, this is the shortest bar that can be used in normal models before descending into minifigure scales. As the rigidity of the finished assembly. I would imagine that the assembly would sit tight, as it does make use of friction to hold it's form, but it is extremely flexible and moveable, going to become poseable